# CoreData fetch nested objects

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, core-data, restkit

I have a json which contain objects where each object have child object, for example

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "obj1"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "obj2"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "obj3",
        "child": {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "obj2"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "obj4",
        "child": {
            "id": 5,
            "name": "obj5"
        }
    }
]
```

So in core data i have entity MyObject which has relation to child (to itself, to one), and relation to parent (to many)

[image]

So when i try fetch object by predicate like

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"parent.@count = 0"]
```

I got only object with id in [1,3,4], but no with id = 2 (here error) and id = 5 (here all correct), because it's was sets parent when it's mapped when object with id = 3 save to data base.

If no use predicate i got 5 object, include obj5.

But i need fetch from coredata exactly count of object what i got from json.

I need fetch only object with id in [1,2,3,4].

How do i need write predicate, if it's possible?

Comment: So you want to fetch the top level objects, not the nested items in the JSON (which is actually unrelated to which items are parents or children in the data store)?

Comment: Yes, only top, but in base object with id=2, now as second level?

Comment: why is it wrong, that you don't get obj2? With obj3 you add a parent to obj2, so it's parent `count` is > 0

Comment: You can't predicate on that in your current model. You can perhaps get the mapping result with that detail, not even sure about that as the children are still processed as part of that key path mapping... Why do you need the top level objects and is there anything else in the JSON ?

Answer (score 1):

The data you got from JSON is a subset of all your objects, but the logic according to which it is selected is not persisted in your object model.

You persist the relationship between child and parent (hint: for readability, rename it as `parents` if it is to-many), but the selection in your JSON example is not based on any of those criteria.

One easy way to get all the objects is to extract the top level ids delivered by the JSON feed and use that in the predicate:

```
NSArray *ids = [jsonArray valueForKey:@"id"];
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"idNumber in %@", ids];
```

*(Note that I changed your attribute name from `id` to `idNumber` in order to avoid possible language quirks, as `id` is a reserved word.)*